# error set selected option value jsp page

Tags: jsp

I'm a new jsp.Now, i try to set selected for option like this:

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test = "${listMonth ne null}">
        <c:forEach items = "${listMonth}" var = "lsMonth">
            <c:choose>
                <c:when test = "${lsMonth == month}">
                    <option value = "${lsMonth}" selected = "selected">${lsMonth}</option>
                </c:when>
                <c:otherwise>
                    <c:choose>
                        <c:when test = "${lsMonth == monthNow}">
                            <option value = "${lsMonth}" selected = "selected">${lsMonth}</option>
                        </c:when>
                        <c:otherwise>
                            <option value = "${lsMonth}">${lsMonth}</option>
                        </c:otherwise>
                   </c:choose>
                </c:otherwise>
            </c:choose>
        </c:forEach>
    </c:when>
</c:choose>
```

but, it's not selected when ${lsMonth == month) , just selected when ${lsMonth == monthNow}.Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Please try

JSTL empty check

```
<c:when test = "${not empty listMonth}">
```

JSTL equivalent

```
<c:if test="${lsMonth eq month}">
```

Comment: i did it.But not working, when lsMonth eq yearNow and lsMonth eq year, there are two selected option value.I try to follow <c: when test = "${lsMonth eq monthNow && lsMonth ne month}" > , it's not working too